# iPhone 6 not displaying in IBM Test Workbench Mobile Devices Tab

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

**Tool:** IBM Mobilefirst TestWorkbench 8.6.0.1
**OS:** Windows 7 
**Device**: iPhone 6    **Version**: 8.1.2

Laptop and iPhone are on same Network. 
Click on Add Devices icon in Mobile Devices tab. Test Workbench URL pops up. 
Entered the URL in my Safari browser in iPhone. 
IBM Rational Test Workbench Mobile Client opens in my browser.
**Problem**
The Device does not show up in Mobile Devices Tab.

Able to record a Test in my iPhone6. After recording, getting a pop up in Test Workbench which says "Click here to generate Test Recordings". When i click that i get the below error in Error log

**Plug-in:** com.ibm.rational.test.lt.recorder.moeb 
**Message:** CRRTWM1201E Unexpected exception while performing test generation. 

**Exception Stack Trace:** 
java.io.IOException: Unable to access device used for recording.
    at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.recorder.moeb.ui.wizards.CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.getSessionProducer(CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.java:150)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.recorder.moeb.ui.wizards.CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.createRecordingSession(CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.java:128)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.recorder.moeb.ui.wizards.CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.access$0(CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.java:125)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.recorder.moeb.ui.wizards.CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard$1.run(CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.recorder.moeb.ui.wizards.CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.performFinish(CreateTestFromRecordingLogsWizard.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)

**Problem Guesses**: Had instrumented the iOS app in Mac with jdk1.6 
Presently uploaded the instrumented iOS app in Test Workbench in Windows Laptop which has jdk1.7. Could this be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

No the jdk should not be the issue.
The fact that your device doesn't appear in the mobile devices tab is not normal. This seems to be the origin of the issue.

The version 8.6.0.1 seems to be old... I recommand first that you update to the last one (8.7), re-instrumente the app and try again please ?

Thanks
Dominique

Comment: Have updated Test Workbench to 8.7 in Mac. Updated IBM MobileFirst Studio to 7.0.0.                                                                           Hit the Test Workbench URL in my Safari browser and IBM Mobile Client displays on Web page in my Mobile. But not able to view the Device in Devices Tab in Test Workbench